# Are there any issues with having a non-generic method in a generic class?

Tags: c#, generics

On MSDN (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/), it says:

> Generic methods can appear on generic or nongeneric types. It is important to note that a method is not generic just because it belongs to a generic type, or even because it has formal parameters whose types are the generic parameters of the enclosing type. A method is generic only if it has its own list of type parameters. In the following code, only method G is generic.

Isn't M for all intents and purposes generic? If you call method M on some instance of type T, M can only have input and output parameters of type T.
Would there be any issues with using such a nongeneric method M?

```
class A
{
    T G<T>(T arg)
    {
        T temp = arg;
        //...
        return temp;
    }
}
class Generic<T>
{
    T M(T arg)
    {
        T temp = arg;
        //...
        return temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: What makes you think generic classes shouldn't have non-generic methods?  (And no, `M` isn't a generic method because it doesn't declare any type parameters itself.)

Comment: No, `M` is not generic, it only happens to be inside a generic class. If you `var myGeneric = new Generic<Car>();` you cannot get a `Bike` using the `T M(T arg)` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Isn't M for all intents and purposes generic?

If you use reflection to inspect those methods, you'll find that `IsGenericMethod` and `IsGenericMethodDefinition` are true for `A.G`, and false for `Generic<>.M`. This is true even though `Generic<>.M`'s return type is `T`, whose `IsGenericParameter` property is true.

You're asking a question about semantics (i.e. the linguistic meaning of "generic method"), and Microsoft has defined the meaning of these concepts as they pertain to C#. So when Microsoft says that a generic method is one that takes generic type arguments, that's the definition that's going to be accepted, both by developers and by the framework itself.

> If you call method M on some instance of type T, M can only have input and output parameters of type T.

Yes, the difference is in the scope of the type `T`. For example, if you have an instance of `Generic<string>`, you cannot pass its `M` an `int`. With the generic method, the generic arguments can be changed at the method level, whereas a non-generic method on a generic class uses types that match the generic types of the class that it belongs to.

> Would there be any issues with using such a nongeneric method M?

There are no "issues" with using a non-generic method like `M` inside of a generic class. That's how generic classes were meant to work. Just be aware of the differences in behavior I mentioned above.

Comment: The phrase "a generic method is one that takes generic type arguments" is ambiguous, unfortunately: one can read it as "a method that takes _generic-type_ arguments" (as in, normal function parameter arguments which just-so-happen to be type-parameters) - or you can read it as "a method that takes generic _type-arguments_" (which is a slightly better reading as it specifically refers to type-parameter-arguments - but yeah, English is not my favourite language...

Comment: @Dai: I think anybody reading this in context will understand what it means, but if you want to propose more precise wording, feel free.

Comment: but it's the weekend :(

Comment: @Dai Let's go down the rabbit-hole....... The second understanding seems to imply a `T`-typed normal parameter which is constrained `where T : Type`, which would certainly be a rather strange understanding. I don't think you can understand that to instead mean "type-arguments which are generic" (so `int` argument for parameter `T`) as all type arguments are for generic parameters anyway. A perhaps slightly understandable version would be a type argument which is *itself* generic, such as `U` argument for the `T` parameter (eg when `U` is a generic parameter from the calling function) ..... :-)